Gaps in submission numbers
The webform uses the page wizard and is quite long (11 pages). The submission numbers are showing gaps e.g. submissions 231, 232, 233, 240, 241 etc.. What would cause the gaps between submission 233 to 240? Note I am referring to the submission number not the submission ID. Could this be the result of users closing their browsers and not completing the form? In some cases users may take over an hour to complete the form.  Are gaps in submission numbers considered normal?
